# Compute bcrypt hash from command line

Tags: password, command, hashsum

I would like to compute the [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) hash of my password.

Is there an open source command line tool that would do that ?

I would use this hash in the Syncthing configuration file (even if I know [from here](https://forum.syncthing.net/t/password-recovery/901) that I can reset the password by editing the config file to remove the user and password in the gui section, then restart Syncthing).

Answer (score 99):

You can (ab)use `htpasswd` from *apache-utils* package, provided you have version 2.4 or higher.

```bash
htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" password | tr -d ':\n'
```

`-b` takes the password from the second command argument
`-n` prints the hash to stdout instead of writing it to a file
`-B` instructs to use bcrypt
`-C 10` sets the bcrypt *cost* to 10

The bare htpasswd command outputs in format *<name>:<hash>* followed by two newlines. Hence the empty string for name and `tr` stripping the colon and newlines.

The command outputs bcrypt with `$2y$` prefix, which may be problem for some uses, but can easily be fixed by another `sed` since the OpenBSD variant using `$2a$` is compatible with the fixed crypt_blowfish variant using `$2y$`.

```bash
htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" password | tr -d ':\n' | sed 's/$2y/$2a/'
```

Link to htpasswd man page: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html
Details about bcrypt variants: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225192/6732096

Comment: This version has a problem with the BCrypt implementation of Java Spring Security. The password to hash must be terminated with a null character. Spring Security seems to do it correctly. I think htpasswd is not doing this correctly.

Comment: @k_o_: Can you be more specific on "has a problem"? All bcrypt implementations use the null-character terminator. Some, like py-bcrypt have even additional checks to ensure that null-character isn't a part of password. You can check the [Apache implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/apr/blob/trunk/crypto/crypt_blowfish.c). I'm using htpasswd with the additional sed to populate database records for multiple Spring applications without problems (that's actually how I come to the answer).

Comment: I was assuming that leaving out the null character was a problem of htpasswd to explain the different encodings between Spring and htpasswd. The output from bcrypt using the other answer's Python approach was producing the same results like in Spring, but htpasswd was not. Maybe also my htpasswd version is quite old, I think the binary was not updated since 2 years.

Comment: There is yet another problem with Spring Security and BCrypt hashes generated with `htpasswd`. Spring Security (at least, certain versions) requires salt revision to be 'a' (so that the hashed password start with '$2a$'), but for me htpasswd generated revision 'y' ('$2y$....') and I was not able to find a way to specify the revision via command line. I then just abandoned `htpasswd` and generated the password using Spring Security code.

Comment: The `tr` can be replaced with `sed -E '/^:/s/:(.*)$/\1/p;d'` (at least, on linux) to avoid stripping the one newline you might want to keep.

Comment: You can supply a version to Spring BcryptPasswordEncoder : "Clients can optionally supply a "version" ($2a, $2b, $2y)" source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html

Answer (score 12):

You can use a Python library. On my Fedora system I did:

```
sudo dnf search bcrypt
```

(the sudo is just to avoid wasting space for a user dnf cache) and from the result can see there is a Python2 and Python3 package:

```
py-bcrypt.x86_64 : Python bindings for OpenBSD's Blowfish password hashing code
python3-py-bcrypt.x86_64 : Python 3 bindings for OpenBSD's Blowfish password hashing code
```

Install the Python2 version and list the files in the package:

```
sudo dnf install py-bcrypt.x86_64
rpm -ql py-bcrypt.x86_64
```

This shows there is a file `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py` so I can get the documentation with

```
pydoc bcrypt
```

This shows me enough to write the following command which will hash the string `"password"`:

```
$ python -c 'import bcrypt; print(bcrypt.hashpw("password", bcrypt.gensalt(log_rounds=10)))'
$2a$10$vWFRZgbOx6RKOKYxCTtyWuMJM60E90Vdm/.0nj.X/o3dYUxvQ/2Dm
```

For later versions of `bcrypt` use `rounds=` instead of `log_rounds=`.

Comment: As of April 2018 the parameter `log_rounds` seems to have changed to `rounds` making it `python -c 'import bcrypt; print(bcrypt.hashpw("password", bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=10)))'`.

Answer (score 6):

This is relevant for FreeBSD, since htpasswd isn't available without installing apache. Building on @meuh's answer, here's how to use Python3 in FreeBSD to get a bcrypt hash of a password - for example, for basic auth in a traefik jail.

Note the following assumes a jail. Be careful with pip if this is the base OS. Adjust for version of Python3 depending on FreeBSD version and current Python3 versions available on it.

```bash
pkg install py37-pip
pip install bcrypt
```

And run, again adjusting for Python 3 version:

```bash
python3.7 -c 'import bcrypt; print(bcrypt.hashpw(b"PASSWORD", bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=15)).decode("ascii"))'
```

@Stuart Cardall rightly points out that this lands your password in history. "Left to the reader" to take this Python3 snippet and expand by a prompt for username and password, so that this information doesn't end up visible in `ps` output or history.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a recent PHP installed, you can do it inline

```bash
echo -n "mynewpass" | php -r 'echo(password_hash(file_get_contents("php://stdin"), PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n");'
```

Just keep in mind the **-n** on echo, if your input may contain newlines, then you will need to trim those off first.

A more interactive version:

```bash
declare a;
printf '\nEnter the password:\n'
stty -echo
read -sr -- a;
stty +echo

printf '%s' "$a" | \
    php -r 'echo(password_hash(file_get_contents("php://stdin"), PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n");';
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional to `@Disassembler`'s answer:

- it's not a good idea to pass passwords in from the command line (as
  the password could be viewable with `ps`)
- `15` is a good balance for complexity / password generation speed

Wrapper script for `htpasswd` & `bcrypt`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

## bcrypt passwd generator ##
#############################
CMD=$(which htpasswd 2>/dev/null)
OPTS="-nBC 15"
USERNAME=$1

usage() {
        local script=$(basename $0)
        cat <<EOF
$script: Generate Bcrypt Hashed Passwords using htpasswd

Usage: $script username
EOF
        exit 1
}

check_config() {
    if [ -z $CMD ]; then
        printf "Exiting: htpasswd is missing.\n"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ -z "$USERNAME" ]; then
            usage
    fi
}

check_config $USERNAME
printf "Generating Bcrypt hash for username: $USERNAME\n\n"
$CMD $OPTS $USERNAME
exit $?
```

Comment: And unless you start the command line with a space, the password will go to your shell history (an file that is probably not encrypted).

Comment: @GabrielDevillers yup, same here. I added "-i" to OPTS and "" to the 2nd-to-last line.

Comment: for BASH & mySQL history for the `root` user it's a good idea to create a symbolic link to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Regarding @GabrielDevillers's comment, perhaps worth mentioning that adding a space to the start doesn't always hide an item from shell history -- depends on the shell and settings.

Answer (score 1):

Following process worked for me!

I have installed `httpd-tools` using the following command in CentOS8

```
yum install httpd-tools -y
```

Then executed the `htpasswd` command like below:

```
htpasswd -bnBC 8 "" password | grep -oP '\$2[ayb]\$.{56}'
```

You may replace the `password` with your one :)

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 20.04 I had to install python3-bcrypt package

```
apt install python3-bcrypt
```

and generated password using this script:

```py
import getpass
import bcrypt

password = getpass.getpass("password: ")
hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt())
print(hashed_password.decode())
```

Script taken from here: https://computingforgeeks.com/secure-prometheus-server-with-basic-password-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

On **OpenBSD** you would simply use the `encrypt` [built-in command](https://man.openbsd.org/encrypt):

```
$ encrypt -b 9 -p
Enter string:
$2b$09$gj37KUAG4QhjKM5wqsPWv.zSzoqF2EH/PzF30.Vtpqiiz3lC4meEq
```

`-b` is the number of hashing rounds.
`-p` prompts the user for a string

When `-p` is not provided it reads the string from the standard input:

```
encrypt -b 15 < secret.txt
$2b$15$4j0cIg5WC3VPPjPIgojfNeNLXnpdYCKu19fPf90NTd6OYXCJmW7ry
```